# C++ edit, compile and execute on Termux

Tags: android, c++, termux

I would like to be able to download a set of files from Drive on to my tablet (Nexus 7 2012 running Lineage OS) and then edit, compile and execute the relevant files. These files are all c++ related .cpp, .h and the main file. (BTW I am new to c++ and Termux).

When I currently do this I can edit and compile but cannot execute - I get a permission denied error message. I have followed the instructions from the termux help page, run termux-setup-storage and given permission for the emulator to access the shared folders. These are all setup correctly as far as I can tell.

Checking up on other questions and sites it is well explained that you cannot compile and run on the emulated storage locations (nor the external drive if you have one - I don't).

My issue is that I cannot copy the files from the emulated download folder into the termux folder. I cannot directly download from drive to the termux folder, and do not know how to navigate directly to Drive from within termux.

So more specifically:

1. How do you copy a file from the emulated termux downloads into the termux folder? (adding su does not work).
2. Is it possible to navigate via termux directly into drive and to work there?
3. I have tried to chmod the files in termux but this does not work. I have also tried termux-open and this does not work. Is there some other way to compile and execute c++ files in termux using clang++?

Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `termux-setup-storage` package maps all the Chromebook Files folders to a new folder in your home directory. To install it, type the following in your termux

```
pkg install termux-setup-storage
```

Then if you type in your termux

```
cd
ls storage/downloads
```

You should see the content of your Chromebook's Download folder. On my chromebook, the `storage` folder contains the following Chromebook Files folders

```
~ $ ls storage/
dcim/      downloads/ movies/    music/     pictures/  shared/
```

I usually put cpp code in my termux user directory (e.g., `~/src/project1`), instead of the Chromebook's directories. Both compiling and execution with `g++` seems fine so far (see the screenshot below). Let me know if you have more specific questions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`termux-setup-storage` used to access the files in `/storage/emulated/0/`, but you can't execute the files in that directory, so that copy the files that you want to compile , put it in  termux home directory `~/`.